# installation part error occur please help me

Tags: software-installation

I've attached an image of the error message I get when installing Java on an Ubuntu virtual box:

[image: Error message]

Please help me rectify the error.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version. Did you run `sudo apt update`?

Answer (score 1):

Check in software sources if `ubuntu universe` and `ubuntu multiverse` are enabled

You can find Software Sources under the dash, the selection is under the 2nd tab `Other Software`

Then type in the terminal

```
sudo apt update && apt install openjdk-7-jdk
```